# Angular on icon click toggle class name or part of the class name

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 11 and in my component.html file I have an icon:

```
<i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

What I need to do is to toggle the class when I click on it.

I need to toggle between:

```
<i class="fa fa-eye aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

and

```
<i class="fa fa-eye-slash aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.ts file :**

```
@Component
export class YourComponent extends ... {
   toggle:boolean = false; // add any public variable
}
```

**.html file :**

```
<i [ngClass]="toggle ? 'fa-eye' : 'fa-eye-slash'" class="fa" aria-hidden="true"
(click)="toggle = !toggle"></i>
```

Comment: Writting if's inside html is a very bad practice, better to write some function like formatClassName and there should be your if statements implementation